# Removing the down side of rectangle when the swirl is above it?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have created a rectangle of blue color in illustrator and then have make a swirl(yellow) using pen tool by giving it stroke. Now i want to remove the blue part of rectangle down under  swirl in easy way.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Select the yellow path with the Selection Tool (Black arrow)
- Edit > Copy (<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>)
- Edit > Paste In Front (<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>)
- Object > Path > Join (<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>) *[ You may need to add an anchor and move a portion of the yellow to fully encompass that area of blue. ]*
- Swap the stoke and fill color on the pasted copy so it has a yellow fill and no stroke (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>)
- Select the blue rectangle and this new yellow shape with the Selection Tool (black arrow)
- Pathfinder Panel > Minus Front (top row, second button from the left)
- Move blue rectangle backwards (<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>)
- Done! :)

**

### Second method:

**

- Select > Select All (<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>)
- Grab the Shape Builder tool in the Tool Bar
- Hold Down the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key and click the area you want to remove.
- Done! :)